# ¿Cómo calcular los estadísticos básicos?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Supongamos una muestra de valores como la siguiente:

```
DECLARE @Ejemplo TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Valor NUMERIC(15,2))

INSERT INTO @Ejemplo (Valor) VALUES (1), (3), (7), (3)
```

Y queremos generar los estadísticos clásicos, esto son:

Centro:

- Media
- Mediana
- Moda

Dispersión:

- Varianza
- Desviación estándar
- Rango

Distribución

- Cuartiles

¿Cómo podemos lograr esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varios de estos estadísticos ya están disponibles desde la versión 2008 (al menos): la media o [`AVG()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), la varianza o [`VAR()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/var-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), la desviación estándar [`STDEV()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stdev-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). El rango puede calcularse con un clásico `MAX() - MIN()`, Para la Moda hay que buscar el elemento más frecuente con un `GROUP BY`  y ordenando por el `COUNT() DESC`. El problema es la Mediana y eventualmente los cuantiles, para la primera podemos consultar las alternativas en [What is the fastest way to calculate the median? de Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median), y para los cuantiles (y eventualmente también podría emplearse para la mediana) usamos una función incorporada, entiendo en la versión 2014,  [`PERCENTILE_CONT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
DECLARE @Median DECIMAL(15, 2);
DECLARE @Moda   DECIMAL(15, 2);
DECLARE @Q25    DECIMAL(15, 2);
DECLARE @Q50    DECIMAL(15, 2);
DECLARE @Q75    DECIMAL(15, 2);

SELECT  @Median = AVG(1.0 * Valor)
FROM
(
    SELECT o.Valor, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.Valor), c.c
        FROM @Ejemplo AS o
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT c = COUNT(*) FROM @Ejemplo) AS c
) AS x
WHERE rn IN ((c + 1)/2, (c + 2)/2);

SELECT  TOP 1 @Moda = Valor
    FROM @Ejemplo
    GROUP BY Valor
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, Valor

SELECT  TOP 1 
    @Q25 = PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Valor) OVER (),
    @Q50 = PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Valor) OVER (),
    @Q75 = PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Valor) OVER ()
    FROM @Ejemplo

SELECT  AVG(T.Valor) AS 'Media',
    @Median          AS 'Mediana',
    @Moda            AS 'Moda',
    VAR(T.Valor)     AS 'Varianza',
    STDEV(T.Valor)   AS 'Desviación Std.',
    MIN(T.Valor)     AS 'Mínimo',
    MAX(T.Valor)     AS 'Máximo',
    MAX(T.Valor) - MIN(T.Valor)
                     AS 'Rango (Diff)',
    @Q25             AS 'Q25',
    @Q50             AS 'Q50',
    @Q75             AS 'Q75'
    FROM    @Ejemplo T
```

El resultado:

```
+----------+---------+------+-------------------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------------+------+------+------+
| Media    | Mediana | Moda | Varianza          | Desviación Std.   | Mínimo | Máximo | Rango (Diff) | Q25  | Q50  | Q75  |
+----------+---------+------+-------------------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------------+------+------+------+
| 3,500000 | 3,00    | 3,00 | 6,333333333333333 | 2,516611478423583 | 1,00   | 7,00   | 6,00         | 2,50 | 3,00 | 4,00 |
+----------+---------+------+-------------------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------------+------+------+------+
```